# how can I drag-and-drop one screen to another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, drag-and-drop

I have a specific question regarding implementing a feature in my Flutter app. I'm currently working on a screen that utilizes a TabBar with two buttons, essentially representing two separate screens. What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to drag a card from the first screen and drop it onto the second screen. Essentially, I want to enable a drag-and-drop functionality between these two screens.

To simplify, imagine having a list of cards on the first screen, and when I drag one of these cards and hover it over the button corresponding to the second screen on the TabBar, I want the second screen to open up, allowing me to drop the card onto it.

Could you please guide me on how to implement this logic effectively? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I've created a screen where I implemented drag-and-drop functionality successfully within the same screen. However, I'm facing difficulty enabling the drag-and-drop of a list card from one screen to another.

What I expected to happen was that I could drag a card from the first screen and drop it onto the second screen.

However, what actually resulted is that I'm unable to drag the card to the second screen as intended.

I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to achieve this functionality between two screens effectively.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/drag-a-widget

Comment: this drap and drop is within one screen. i want it drag and drop one screen to other screen

Comment: "and when I drag one of these cards and hover it over the button ..." you want to drag one widget over another one and when dropping you wanna go to a new screen don't you?

Comment: yes exactly that i want sir please guide me how can i implement it ?

Comment: here you can find out how to detect the drop action: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/drag-a-widget#drop-the-draggable